# Trouble settting up Data validation rule prior to new data insertion into a table

Tags: ms-access-2013

requirement: 
prevent new data entry into myTBL if fieldA = {newly entered data for this field}
and fieldBdate = {newly entered date for this field and alert the user}

environment: ms access 365

I intend to use the following statement via Validation Rule,

= [myTBL.fieldA] <> FORM![fieldA]" & "[myTBL.fieldBdate] <> FORM![fieldBdate]
err msg: complained invalid syntax.

what's the correct syntax for this?  Thanks.

Comment: Just one question, why the spaces in " & " ?

Comment: good catch on the the two double quotes.  have removed them includes spaces, however, still got error of complaining the FORM field not found, and I've even named such a form, FORMS![myTBLview1]![fieldA] and such a form does exist.